# Why is unskip not working here?

Tags: spacing, macros, text-decorations

I'm trying to define a macro to be used as follows:

```
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\newcommand{\thesis}[1]{\uline{\ignorespaces #1\unskip}}
% underlining required by school - I know, I know

% later...

\thesis{
  This is the beginning of a multi-line thesis statement.
  I use one sentence on each line throughout my document.
  Thus, the thesis is broken as in XKCD 1285.
}
```

The problem is that the `\unskip` doesn't gobble the final line break. If I add a comment (like `as in XKCD 1285.%`) then it works as expected, but isn't this what `\unskip` is supposed to do?

The initial space is gobbled correctly. Without `\ignorespaces` there is an underlined space at the beginning, but `\ignorespaces` removes it. The `\unskip` is supposed to remove the underlined statement at the end, but doesn't.

My understanding is that `\unskip` is kind of like `\ignorepreviousspace`. Is this correct?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\newcommand{\thesis}[1]{\uline{\ignorespaces #1\unskip}}
\begin{document}
\thesis{
  Foo.
  Bar.
  Baz.
} % comment at end of previous line gives desired output
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`\uline` parses its argument to divide the text into words. A parsed word is put into a box to measure its width and overlay it with the markings (line, double line, wave, ...). Therefore `\unskip` goes at start of a new word to the begin of a box. There is no space to remove. Thus it is without effect.

Putting `\unskip` *after* `\uline{...}` is better because it removes glue. But `\uline` inserts *two* of them at the place of a space. The first is the underlined space (`\leaders`), the second is a small negative space (-1/300 in), probably added to get a better overlapping of the underline segments.

Adding only one `\unskip` after `\uline` in the [other, now deleted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/166161/16967) (visible only for 10K+ users), if the line end after `\thesis` is removed by a comment, works by an accident. At the end of a paragraph TeX removes the last space by an implicit `\unskip`.

### Solution with two `\unskip`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\newcommand*{\thesis}[1]{%
  \uline{\ignorespaces #1}%
  \unskip\unskip
}

\begin{document}
Before. \thesis{
  Foo.
  Bar.
  Baz.
} After.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Solution with package `trimspaces`

The next example uses package `trimspaces` to remove the spaces before passing the text to `\uline`. This makes the solution more independent from the implementation of `\uline`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{trimspaces}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\thesis}[1]{%
  \def\thesis@text{#1}%
  \trim@spaces@in\thesis@text
  \expandafter\uline\expandafter{\thesis@text}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Before. \thesis{
  Foo.
  Bar.
  Baz.
} After.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Heiko, the other answer is deleted and therefore only visible for users with reputation from 10000 on. I added regarding information, but perhaps you find yourself a better solution.

Answer (score 12):

Heiko has given a full description of how to solve the problem so I'll restrict to commenting on the sub-question

> My understanding is that `\unskip` is kind of like `\ignorepreviousspace`. Is this correct?

Basically no, that understanding is not correct. `\unskip`  and `\ignorespaces` work at completely different levels (and `%` before a linebreak works at another level again).

Simplified slightly, TeX reads a sequence of *characters* from the file, turning then into *tokens* (either by reading a group of characters as a command name, or assigning catcode values to character tokens)  Then these lists of tokens are processed and may eventually produce horizontal or vertical *lists* of typeset boxes and glue.

`%` works at the level of *characters*. If a `%` is seen the rest of the characters on that line, and the linebreak at the end of the  line are skipped and not turned into tokens at all.

`\ignorespaces` works at the level of *tokens*. After `\ignorespaces` all space tokens (which normally are ignored in vertical mode, or add inter-word glue in horizontal mode) are ignored until the first non-space token is seen when the commands affect ends.

`\unskip` works at the level of *lists*. If the previous item added to the current horizontal list (whether coming from a space or from an explicit or implicit `\vskip` or `\hskip` is removed from the current list and discarded. (Except on the main vertical list on the page where you may not remove items once added, and `\unskip` is a no-op).

Apart from the fact that they are operating on different structures note (which is relevant to the processing at the end of a paragraph in this question) that `\ignorespaces` ignores any number of consecutive spaces but `\unskip` only ever removed one glue node. Usually of course `\ignorespaces` only sees one space token to ignore as you have to work to get two consecutive tokens as consecutive space *characters* are tokenised as a single space token. But for example `\ignorespaces\space\space` would ignore both.