# Swallow space before command

Tags: white-space

Is there a way to swallow one space (or more spaces) before a command?
E.g.:

```
xxx \mycommand{}yyy
```

which results in

```
xxxyyy
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for `\unskip`.

LaTeX version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}    
xxx \unskip{}yyy
\end{document}
```

Plain-TeX version:

```
xxx \unskip{}yyy
\bye
```

The output of both documents is "xxxyyy".

Comment: Thanks Mico! Is there an equivalent to removing the vertical spaced introduced by environments?

Comment: @NVaughan - Addressing your follow-up question is quite tricky, actually, as you don't specify the types of vertical space or the types of environments that introduce vertical spacing at their end. In principle, `\unskip` works on "glue" in both "horizontal mode" and "vertical mode". However, `\unskip` does *not* work on items (including vertical-mode glue) once they're added to the "main vertical list" on a page. (Warning: Some serious TeX jargon is being thrown about right now!) See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/166622/5001) for more information.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a look.