# I am trying to suppress strange white-space before variable call

Tags: white-space

I have define a variable that changes with a counter as such:

```tex
% Abbreviate after first instance
\newcounter{whocount}
\setcounter{whocount}{0}%
\newcommand{\who}{
    \stepcounter{whocount}
    \ifnum\value{whocount}=1%\ifnum\c@whocount=1%<<<the TeX way
World Health Organisation (W.H.O.)%
    \else%
W.H.O%
    \fi
}
```

If I have a sentence such as the following:

```tex
The \who recommends wearing masks in public.
```

It will output

```
The  World Health Organisation (W.H.O.) recommends wearing masks in public.
```

The only way I can find to fix this would be the following:

```tex
The\ignorespaces\who recommends wearing masks in public.
```

[`\unskip`](http://%5B%60%5Cunskip%60%5D(https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/555640/swallow-space-before-command)%20doesn%27t%20work%20either.) also works as above.

Is there something I can change **in my `\who` definition** to suppress this strange white-space before the word?

Comment: Does `\newcommand{\who}{%` solve your problem?

Comment: There are a few packages that ease the task of inputting acronyms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whitespace comes from the space which is automatically inserted at the end of every line (except if the line ends with a comment). So you need to add `%` at the end of every line which should not add a space:

```
% Abbreviate after first instance
\newcounter{whocount}
\setcounter{whocount}{0}%
\newcommand{\who}{%
    \stepcounter{whocount}%
    \ifnum\value{whocount}=1 % Here you want space to terminate the number
World Health Organisation (W.H.O.)%
    \else
W.H.O%
    \fi
}
```